# Flutter - rest api data br and p tags in futurebuilder

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, flutter, http

I am trying to get rest api data from my website(from my wordpress wp rest api) to flutter app and using http package.
Link : [My Rest APi](http://lilwaqamar.com//wp-json/wp/v2/posts) (You can see at lot of br tags.)
my code is

```
body: FutureBuilder(
      future: wpPostService.getPosts(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Post> posts = snapshot.data;
          return ListView(
            children: posts
                .map((Post post) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(post.title.rendered),
                      subtitle: Text(post.excerpt.rendered),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          );
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }),
```

My problem is that im getting data with `no br and p tags` so my output is looking ugly like imagine a poem without `<br> and <P> tags`.

I am getting no spaces (and line breaks).

Answer (score 0):

Got solution.

subtitle: Html(
data: post.content.rendered.substring(0, 90) + '..',
defaultTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
textStyle: TextStyle(
color: Colors.black54,
letterSpacing: .5,
fontSize: 16),
),
),

```
.substring(0, 90) + '..'
```

is what I was looking for.